# Set initial view in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

How do I change the initial view in an SAPUI5 project? I want to change the view that is being displayed when the route pattern is `""`

Should I change the rootView property in manifest?

```
"rootView": {
        "viewName": "namespace.view.App",
        "type": "XML",
        "id": "app"
      }
```

Kindly help

Comment: Depends on what you mean by _initial view_. Is it the root view? Or the view that should be displayed when the route pattern is `""`? Does the app have a Router at all?

Comment: @BoghyonHoffmann I mean the view that is configured to be displayed when pattern is ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for everyone's assistance and suggestions.

Since the application I was editing used routing and the navigation target resolution service was configured to resolve the empty location hash to the application, I made changes to its routing configuration.

I changed the values in the "routing" configuration's "routes" where pattern was set as `""` to the values of the view I wanted to display when I run the application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can change it there.
Replace viewName with new existing view :)

Answer (score 0):

Change `namespace.view.App` to `namespace.view.NewInitialViewName`.

You can also delete `App.view.xml` and `App.controller.js` if you are not using them.